# Overleaf API - How to programmatically upload an image?

Tags: latex, sharelatex, overleaf

I use [overleaf](https://github.com/overleaf/overleaf) to edit latex documents. The overleaf platform has a feature to upload an image file, which can then be referenced and included in the latex document.

I'm able to manually upload images into the overleaf platform, and use/reference them successfully from my latex document, but I was wondering if there is a way to do the uploading programmatically via an API.

I think I might need to use https://github.com/overleaf/filestore but I'm not sure how to get started.

FYI: My main use case is to do this from Python, specifically a Google Colab notebook.

Comment: I think overleaf has some feature to keep the project synced with a github repo, so you could push your images to the githib repo.

Answer (score 3):

While Overleaf doesn't have its own upload API, [Dropbox does](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#files-upload). To use it to get files into Overleaf,

- Set up [Dropbox synchronization](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/how-to/Dropbox_Synchronization). You'll need a paid account for this.
- Make yourself a [Dropbox app](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/apps?_tk=pilot_lp&_ad=topbar4&_camp=myapps) with 'Full Dropbox Access'.
- Add the 'files.content' permissions to your app.
- Use that web console to get an OAuth2 token, which you'll pass in below.

Now you can upload files! The HTTP API is [well documented](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#files-upload), but Python at least has [a nice SDK](https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-sdk-python). So for me, programmatic uploading worked out to

```
pip install dropbox
```

```py
import dropbox
from pathlib import Path
from io import BytesIO
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def upload(ax, project, path):
    bs = BytesIO()
    format = path.split('.')[-1]
    ax.figure.savefig(bs, bbox_inches='tight', format=format)

    token = Path('token.txt').read_text()
    dbx = dropbox.Dropbox(token)

    # Will throw an UploadError if it fails
    dbx.files_upload(
        f=bs.getvalue(), 
        path=f'/Apps/Overleaf/{project}/{path}',
        mode=dropbox.files.WriteMode.overwrite)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()

    upload(ax, 'project_name', 'images/test.png')
```

Answer (score 2):

There is an unofficial Python API for overleaf: https://github.com/jkulhanek/pyoverleaf

You can install a CLI by running:

```bash
pip install 'pyoverleaf[cli]'
```

Uploading an image can be done as follows:

```bash
cat image.jpg | pyoverleaf write project-name/image.jpg
```

Alternatively, you can access it from Python:

```py
import pyoverleaf
api = pyoverleaf.Api()
projects = api.get_projects()
project_id = projects[0].id
rootdir = api.project_get_files(project_id)
api.project_upload_file(project_id, rootdir.id, "image.jpg", open("image.jpg", "rb").read())
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the [Overleaf API](https://www.overleaf.com/devs) does not currently allow programmatic upload to existing projects. It's sole purpose is to provide links that can be used to start *new* projects by users who manually click specially crafted links. Instead, you probably want to look at one of Overleaf's [sync options](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/how-to/Working_Offline_in_Overleaf). Currently they offer Git/GitHub and Dropbox options. Once the sync is set up, you could add the files to those sources to allow Overleaf to pull them in.